# White Space Appears Right of Browser Window When at Full Screen

Tags: html, css

There is a giant rectangle of white space to the right and bottom of the browser window when it is at full screen. Does anybody know how to get rid of this?

JSFiddle: http://goo.gl/mTWfsj

Comment: Please **post your code here**. The rule is in place to help you formulate a better problem statement and to review your code yourself. Please avoid using link shorteners.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this style on `.copyright2`

```
.copyright2{

    position: relative;
    left: 17.5%;
}

p {
    width: 100%;
}
```

So `.copyright2` has width: 100% and start at `left: 17.5%`

To fix it remove `left: 17.5%` from `.copyright2`

Here a minimal example to illustrate:

```css
.red{
  background: red;  
  height: 100px;
}

.blue{
  background: blue;  
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Andrew I am glad that my answer has helped you, but please **edit** your question so that it can help future readers.