# float element to right of div appears outside

Tags: html, css

Well, I'm back to doing front-end stuff -- which is really not my forté -- and I'm stumped.

I have a div with a logo, and I need to put some text in-line with it, vertically centered within the div. Every time I try to float the element right, it seems to end up outside of the div (somehow?).

Relevant HTML:

```
   <div id="wrapper-header">
  <div id="wrapper-nav-header">
    <div id="header-logo">
      <span id="header-logo-span"><a href="/"><img src="mylogo.png" /></a></span>
      <span id="header-customer-name">Customer Name</span>
    </div>
  </div>
...
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
   #wrapper-header {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1
}

#wrapper-header #header-logo {
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#wrapper-header #header-logo img {
  max-height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#wrapper-header #header-customer-name {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

What do I need to do to get this header-customer-name element to float right?

Comment: Please add your code to fiddle

Comment: @DecompileCodex, use float:right to name div. you want name in right, right?

Comment: @LaxmikantDange, sorry i did not read about link but its just normal code so i don't think you will need that..

Comment: i have made jsfiddle by the code provided by op.here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/21zxsvq6/

Comment: Your code seems fine @DecompileCodex.

Comment: I suggest don't use `float` it always push the content more than we expect..

Comment: @Amitsingh, yes that's true but if we are using for 2 element then float will be much better with clear:both..right?

Comment: Do you mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/1myxz9pL/ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using flex box:

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrapper-header {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1
}

#header-logo {
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#header-logo img {
  max-height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#header-customer-name {
  flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper-header">
  <div id="wrapper-nav-header">
    <div id="header-logo">
      <span id="header-logo-span"><a href="/"><img src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1" /></a></span>
      <span id="header-customer-name">Customer Name</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or you can calculate an appropriate padding to your `header-customer-name` like this:

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} 
#wrapper-header {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1
}

#header-logo {
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#header-logo img {
  max-height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#header-customer-name {
  float: right;
    padding: 12px 0; /*you can change for a more precise value*/
}
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper-header">
  <div id="wrapper-nav-header">
    <div id="header-logo">
      <span id="header-logo-span"><a href="/"><img src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1" /></a></span>
      <span id="header-customer-name">Customer Name</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyway if you're referring that the `header-customer-name` is outing on the right of the `#wrapper-header` that is probably because it has `position: fixed` and `width: 100%`, that's why I add the style:

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Check my answer here to better understanding [White Space Appears Right of Browser Window When at Full Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839707/white-space-appears-right-of-browser-window-when-at-full-screen/31840077#31840077)

---

This has no relation with the question but can help you

**Don’t Overqualify**

As a general rule, don’t supply more information than is necessary.

```
// bad
ul#someid {..}
.menu#otherid{..}
#id1 #id2{...}

// good
#someid {..}
#otherid {..}
#id2{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/S9WQv/442/)

Change style to this way..

```
#wrapper-header #header-customer-name {
vertical-align: middle;
float: right;
padding-top: 15px;  /*value suits to your logo */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have CSS reset code in CSS files which is linked with this page. After the is below css reset added, the problem was solved. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7bzmf62b/1/)**

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```